# Does a true hallucination need to go away while plugging one's ears?

Tags: hallucinations

Can an auditory hallucination be true hallucination even if the person clàims that it doesnot reduces in volume when he plugs his ears. Similarly can a visual hallucination still be a true hallucination even when it doesn't disappear when person closes his eyes??

Answer (score 3):

A hallucination is [a perception in the absence of external stimulus that has qualities of real perception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination) and hallucinations can occur in different ways.

Visual hallucinations can occur with the eyes open or [closed](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-cause-of-closed-eye-visual-hallucinations) ([see also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-eye_hallucination)).  Visual hallucinations can also occur with people who have [lost their sight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_release_hallucinations)

Just like visual hallucinations, auditory hallucinations can also occur with the ears open or plugged.  To highlight the point, I suffer with [tinnitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinnitus) and I hear the noise with my ears plugged or open. Auditory hallucinations can also occur in people with [hearing loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_ear_syndrome)